# Remove duplicate numbers in an array in C:

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, duplicates, complexity-theory

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[20], t = 0; //20-t is the new size of array.

    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i<20-t; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j<20-t; j++)
        {
            if(array[i] == array[j])
            {
                for(int z = j; z<20-t; z++)
                    array[z] = array[z+1];//shift numbers.
                    t++; 
                    i = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program works fine but I am not sure why it does when i = -1 but not when i = 0? I would also like to know the complexity of this code.

```
for(int i = 0; i<20-t; i++)
    printf("%d ", array[i]); //Array after duplicates have been removed.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the posted code has several instances of the 'magic' number 20.  This makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug and maintain.  Suggest using #define to give the 'magic' number a meaningful name and using that meaningful name throughout the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write the program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   20

int main( void )
{
    int a[N];
    int n;
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) scanf( "%d", &a[i] );

    n = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int j = 0;
        while ( j < n && a[i] != a[j] ) ++j;
        if ( j == n ) a[n++] = a[i];
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

then the complexity of the algorithm will be O( N ^ 2 ).

As for your algorithm then its complexity is  O( N ^ 3 ).

That is you approach is less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your inner loop access elements in [z, 20-t+1], which is 1 element beyond the array. The 'shift numbers' loop should be:

```
for(int z = j; z<20-t-1; z++)
    array[z] = array[z+1];//shift numbers.
```

To reply your question, it works with `i = -1` because `i` is going to be incremented by the for-j loop. Therefore it will be 0 next iteration (and not 1, thereby skipping 1 element).

Said that, what you need to do is decrement the `j` iterator instead, i.e.:

```
t++; --j;
```

It will run faster!